# In what versions of Windows are Storage Management API Classes such as 'MSFT_PhysicalDisk' implemented?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I am trying pull metrics such as 'MediaType' from MSFT_PhysicalDisk. I'm successful on a Windows 10 machine, but not on a Windows 7 machine.

On what type of machines is MSFT_PhysicalDisk available?

The reference for Storage Management API Classes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/storage-management-api-classes

See code below for an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
bool isSsd;
try
{
    var physDiskQuery =
        $"SELECT MediaType FROM MSFT_PhysicalDisk WHERE DeviceID='{driveNumber.Value}'";

    var wmiScope = @"\\.\root\microsoft\windows\storage";
    using (var physicalDiskSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, physDiskQuery))
    {
        var objectCollection = physicalDiskSearcher.Get();
        var physicalDisk = objectCollection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (physicalDisk == null)
            return null;

        isSsd = (ushort)physicalDisk["MediaType"] == 4;
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Error while checking for SSD drive. Details: {exception.GetBaseException()}");
    return null;
}

return isSsd;
```

Comment: At the very bottom of the [`MSFT_PhysicalDisk` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh830532.aspx) (accessible from the link you provided) under the Requirements section it says "Minimum supported client: Windows 8."

Comment: MS pages generally list the minimum required version, with the exception that XP support has been removed from many pages so XP-compatible functions are now listed as requiring Vista.

Comment: Thanks @BACON. You should probably add that as the answer. I guess I was not patient enough to scroll to the bottom of the page!

Comment: Marked back up from -1 to 0 because I found this post useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN documentation lists requirements *way* at the bottom of the page.  For the [`MSFT_PhysicalDisk` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh830532.aspx) it says...

> **Minimum supported client:** Windows 8 [desktop apps only]
>
> **Minimum supported server:** Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps only]

In other words, you need at least [Windows version 6.2](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases).

Comment: Has anyone found an alternative to MSFT_PhysicalDisk on Windows 7?